# How to get past/ended public events from facebook using graph api/FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-events

I tried using the since and until parameters to get past events but it doesnt seem to work. The results from using since and until parameters give only events that have an end date in the future and a start date within the specified time limit. But however i would like to retrieve a list of all public events within the specified limit irrespective of whether it is still active or not. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use FQL for that:

```
select eid, name, start_time from event where creator = {page_id} and start_time >= "2014-05-01T00:00:00+0200" and start_time <= "2014-05-31T23:59:59+0200"
```

Make sure that {page_id} is a valid Page ID (or User ID). See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/ as reference.

Comment: thanks...but i want to get all public events that contain a keyword...so i dont know the page_id/user_id beforehand...Also even in graph api giving time limits say 2014-05-01 to 2014-05-31 works (near past or includes the current)..but say i give 2013-11-01 to 2013-12-01 doesnt work..